# What database does Maxmind use for timezone IDs?

Tags: timezone, jodatime, maxmind

I'm using Maxmind's GeoIP2 products to extract timezone IDs and then using JodaTime to parse/manipulate those timezones. I've noticed that there are timezones that are returned form GeoIP2 that are not in JodaTime's available list of timezones, such as `"Europe/Kirov"`

I'd like to properly parse all timezones, but without insight into what timezone database/directory Maxmind is using, I don't know how to begin. Does anyone know what they're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MaxMind pulls the geographical data in GeoIP2 from [GeoNames](http://geonames.org/), which uses the [IANA Time Zone Database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). See [this file](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/zone.tab#L333) for `Europe/Kirov`. This entry was added in the 2016d release of the IANA database. JodaTime 2.9.4 should include it.